# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'birds_eye'

Tags: python, django

I've recently started to learn how to build django projects with multiple apps. I have learnt that by using `from . import views` I can import the different views from the current directory that I am in. However, when using this method, the prompt would give me an error saying: `ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'birds_eye'`

The following is my current directory tree of my django project:

```
birds_eye
|- accounts (app folder)
|- birds_eye (actual project folder)
|- clubs (app folder)
|- events (app folder)
|- posts (app folder)
|- static
|- templates
```

And this is the actual code of what is happening:

```
birds_eye
|- birds_eye (actual project folder)
    |- urls.py
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("test/", views.TestPage.as_view(), name="test"),
    path("thanks", views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name="thanks"),
    path('accounts/', include("accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),

    # Events --> Calendar, Posts --> Feed | Expected to finish later on. Uncomment when done.
    # path("posts/", include("posts.urls", namespace="posts")),
    # path("events/", include("events.urls", namespace="events")),
    
    path("clubs/", include("clubs.urls", namespace="clubs")),
    path('surveys', include('djf_surveys.urls')),
]
```

Is there any solution to this?
(I can edit the question in order to provide more resources from my project)

Comment: Do you have `views.py` file inside the inner `birds_eye` folder where the `urls.py` in?

Comment: Oh wait, I just found out that I never had a `views.py` for the inner birds_eye folder where the `urls.py`. I'll work on to that and then if it doesn't work I'll come back here.

Comment: Yay, got it to work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you have missed `views.py` file inside the folder where you have `urls.py`. You can create a new one or import the view functions from another app or folder as AshSmith88 explained. You might want to check alternative relative import examples from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `views.py` file in the same directory as your `urls.py` file. I assume your `views` are in your other apps (clubs, posts, etc)?

You would be better to import each view directly from those apps, e.g. in your `urls.py`

```
from ..clubs.views import ...
```

Alternatively, if you do want to carry on down the route you are on. Create a `views.py` file in your `birds_eye` folder (same as `urls.py`) and import all the views into there using the same approach as I put above. You should then be able to import views in your current directory and all the views you need will be in there.